# How to link between MongoDB C Driver to my own programs

Tags: c, mongodb

I'm a novice user for MongoDB using C driver, and I can't find any detail tutorial that teach how to create my first MongoDB program in C.

I've created my first program according to http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mongo.h"

int main() {
  mongo conn[1];
  int status = mongo_connect( conn, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );

  if( status != MONGO_OK ) {
      switch ( conn->err ) {
        case MONGO_CONN_SUCCESS:    printf( "connection succeeded\n" ); break;
        case MONGO_CONN_NO_SOCKET:  printf( "no socket\n" ); return 1;
        case MONGO_CONN_FAIL:       printf( "connection failed\n" ); return 1;
        case MONGO_CONN_NOT_MASTER: printf( "not master\n" ); return 1;
      }
  }

  mongo_destroy( conn );

  return 0;
}
```

However, it shows up an error that it can not find where "mongo.h" is. 
Does anyone know how to compile this file so I can link it to the MongoDB C driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go to [C Language Driver docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/C+Language+Center) and download the latest stable code base (v0.4).

This contains mongo.h.  Install it where-ever you want on your computer, and build the library.  You then need to specify the -I to the location of your downloaded headers, and -L for your compiled library.